# The ten's digit and unit's digit of numbers

Tags: c#-3.0

I have this code

```
int[,] array = new int[,]{ {34, 21, 32, 41, 25},
                           {14 ,42, 43, 14, 31},
                           {54, 45, 52, 42, 23}, 
                           {33, 15, 51, 31, 35}, 
                           {21, 52, 33, 13, 23} };

            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(array[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

and i need to find a specific number ( the treasure ).
For each value the ten's digit represents the row number and the unit's digit represents the column number of the cell containing the next clue. 
Starting in the upper left corner (at 1,1), i have to use the clues to guide me search of the array. (The first three clues are 11, 34, 42). 
The treasure is a cell whose value is the same as its coordinates. 
The program should output the cells it visits during its search.

I did the simply way:

```
Console.WriteLine("The next clue is: {0}", array[0, 0]);
Console.WriteLine("The next clue is: {0}", array[2, 3]);
Console.WriteLine("The next clue is: {0}", array[3, 2]);
Console.WriteLine("The next clue is: {0}", array[0, 4]);
```

and so on, but the problem is, that if I change the array to set another route the program will output the wrong way. So the solution needs to be dynamic and find the treasure regardless of the array content.

My problem is that i don't know how to do to find the ten's digit of the numbers and the unit's digit.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Forget code. How do *you*, as a *human*, compute the units digit and the tenths digit? Write down the steps. Break each step down in smaller, simpler steps. Break each of the resulting steps down in simpler, smaller steps again. Repeat until all steps cannot be broken down any more. For each step, think about how you would implement it as a program.

Comment: You can use integer division (by 10) to get the row index (1 based) and the `%` remainder operator to get the units. For example: `34 / 10` -> 3 and `34 % 10` -> 4 (or use `34 - (3 * 10)` since you already know 3)

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment: code below and [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7DgTuI)

(I've added a `HashSet<int>` to track which cells have already been visited and avoid ending up with an infinite loop)

```
int[,] array = new int[,]
{
    {34, 21, 32, 41, 25},
    {14 ,42, 43, 14, 31},
    {54, 45, 52, 42, 23}, 
    {33, 15, 51, 31, 35}, 
    {21, 52, 33, 13, 23} 
};

int currentCoordinates = 11;
bool treasureFound = false;
var visitedCells = new HashSet<int>();

while (!treasureFound && !visitedCells.Contains(currentCoordinates))
{
    int currentRowIndex = currentCoordinates / 10;
    int currentColumnIndex = currentCoordinates % 10;

    int nextCoordinates = array[currentRowIndex - 1, currentColumnIndex - 1];
    if (nextCoordinates == currentCoordinates)
    {
        treasureFound = true;
    }
    else
    {
        visitedCells.Add(currentCoordinates);
        currentCoordinates = nextCoordinates;
    }   
}

if (treasureFound)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Treasure found in cell {currentCoordinates}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No treasure");
}
```